# Does polling work with lightweight checkout?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm using "checkout build script from scm" option, paired with lightweight checkout.

I would like to add repository polling to that.

This is Jenkinsfile that I use:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers {
      pollSCM('H/1 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout([
                        $class                           : 'GitSCM',
                        branches                         : [[name: 'master']],
                        userRemoteConfigs                : [[url: 'file:///home/my-secret-home/workspace/pipeline-test']]])
            }
        }
        stage('Echo!') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo TEST'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Although job is running, git polling log tries to convince me that 'Polling has not run yet.'

Is configuring such behavior possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't work.

With lightweight checkout, the mapping to the remote branches are lost, so git doesn't know where to look for further updates.

[image]

You can also confirm this by running `git pull` on the local repository. It returns:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```